# Mozilla for Android Failed to build on ubuntu

Tags: android, compiler-errors, linker-errors, mozilla, fennec

I'm trying to build Mozilla for Android (Fennec). Every time I got a similar error with different files.

```
   /home/hazem/gecko-dev/js/src/frontend/TokenStream.cpp:1884: error: undefined reference to '__srget'
    20:18.33 /home/hazem/gecko-dev/js/src/jsapi.cpp:3749: error: undefined reference to '__srget'
    20:18.33 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    20:18.33 make[5]: *** [libxul.so] Error 1
    20:18.34 make[4]: *** [toolkit/library/target] Error 2
    20:18.34 make[3]: *** [compile] Error 2
    20:18.34 make[2]: *** [default] Error 2
    20:18.34 make[1]: *** [realbuild] Error 2
    20:18.34 make: *** [build] Error 2
    20:18.35 442 compiler warnings present.
```

What I tried until now:

- change the android sdk to 23 and back to 22.
- change ndk from 8 to 10.
- set JAVA_HOME.
- check execution permission for the files.
  What is going wrong with the build ? and is there anyway to solve this ? 
  thanks in advanced.

Update: 
I used this to link the libraries `sudo ldconfig`

then the following come up:

```
ecl/ecp_521.c:42:27: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
17:25.30 ecl/ecp_521.c:50:18: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
17:25.91 make[4]: *** [config/external/nss/target] Error 2
17:25.91 make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
17:43.23 libdombindings_test_s.a.desc
17:43.27 make[3]: *** [compile] Error 2
17:43.27 make[2]: *** [default] Error 2
17:43.27 make[1]: *** [realbuild] Error 2
17:43.27 make: *** [build] Error 2
```

I think it's a linker error as the problem now in `libdombindings_test_s.a.desc` probably . But I don't knw how to fix this.

Comment: did you try to build with `-j 1` ("one job", no parallelism in the build)?

Comment: I build using '  ./mach build ' . usually its ' -j8 ' .

Comment: `-j 8` builds faster but only `-j 1` gives a readable output. It is too easy to miss error messages with `-j N`